# Please verify this Proportion Hypothesis Test (Statistics)

Tags: statistics

**Questions:**

- $120$ voters, $39$ identify with radical movement.
- does this provide sufficient evidence that more than $25\%$ of voters identify with radical movement?
- use $p$-value approach.

**My Steps:**

(0) Check Requirements $(120)(.25)>10$ and $(120)(.75)>10$ -- passes requirements.

(1) Hypothesis will be using a right tailed test. $H_0 : p = .25; H_1 : p > .25$

(2) No alpha (level of significance) is given, so default to $0.05$.

(3) $Z_t (\text{Test Statistic}) = ((.325-.25)/(\sqrt{(.25)(.75)/120} = 1.897$

(4) $P(Z \ge 1.897) \ge 1 - (\text{about}).9713 = .0287$. Reject $H_o$ if $p$-value is less than alpha.

(5) At the $.05$ level of significance, there is sufficient evidence to support that more than $25\%$ of voters identify with the radical movement.

Does that all look correct? Thank you :-)

Comment: Ah rats, I ran the test for mu instead of p. I will revise my question shortly. (update) -- revised, thanks.

Comment: Step zero still needs editing.  The requirements for a hypothesis test for a proportion are different than those for a hypothesis test for a mean.  Other than that, the work looks correct.

Comment: @DougChatham  -- thank you Doug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the steps all look correct.